# password filter cannot compile in vs2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2012, passwords

I have downloaded some code about password filter in this [place](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=77994&source=navbar). The original project was compiled in vs2008 and vs2010. I updated it to vs2012, and i found it cannot be compiled. How can i fix this, Thank you.

This is the error message:
[image: Error Messages]

```
Error   1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'TCHAR *'    D:\SVN\branch\nobull-branch\util.cpp    72  1   passwdHk
Error   2   error C2664: 'int sprintf_s(char *,size_t,const char *,...)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR *' to 'char *'    D:\SVN\branch\nobull-branch\util.cpp    89  1   passwdHk
Error   3   error C2664: '_strdup' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR *' to 'const char *'    D:\SVN\branch\nobull-branch\util.cpp    91  1   passwdHk
Error   4   error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR *' to 'const char *' D:\SVN\branch\nobull-branch\util.cpp    188 1   passwdHk
Error   5   error C2664: 'pshk_log_write_w' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [28]' to 'LPCWSTR'    D:\SVN\branch\nobull-branch\util.cpp    202 1   passwdHk
Error   6   error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR *' to 'const char *' D:\SVN\branch\nobull-branch\util.cpp    208 1   passwdHk
Error   7   error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR *' to 'const char *' D:\SVN\branch\nobull-branch\util.cpp    211 1   passwdHk
Error   8   error C2664: '_strdup' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR *' to 'const char *'    D:\SVN\branch\nobull-branch\util.cpp    224 1   passwdHk
Error   9   error C2664: 'strlen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR *' to 'const char *' D:\SVN\branch\nobull-branch\util.cpp    229 1   passwdHk
Error   10  error C2446: ':' : no conversion from 'const char *' to 'TCHAR *'   D:\SVN\branch\nobull-branch\util.cpp    249 1   passwdHk
Error   11  error C2664: 'int _snprintf_s(char *,size_t,size_t,const char *,...)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR *' to 'char *'   D:\SVN\branch\nobull-branch\util.cpp    249 1   passwdHk
Error   12  error C2664: 'int _snprintf_s(char *,size_t,size_t,const char *,...)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TCHAR *' to 'char *'   D:\SVN\branch\nobull-branch\util.cpp    254 1   passwdHk
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is highly likely you do not want unicode compilation for your current predicament (erahh... project).

1. Right click your project in the project explorer, select "Properties..."
2. At the very top of the properties dialog is a Configuration selection drop-down list. You likely want to change *all* your configurations (unless for some odd reason you want to build non-Unicode debug, but Unicode release). If you want them all non-Unicode (and you likely do) select "All Configurations".
3. In the left pane immediately under Configuration Properties, select "General"
4. In the right pane, under Project Defaults, find "Character Set"
5. If it is currently set to Unicode Character Set, change it to "Multi-Byte Character Set" or "Not Set" if you're not planning on using MBCS features.
6. Save your project file, and rebuild the world.

Note: some of the the function calls in your APIs are hopefully chosen-via-macro definition. one in particular I'm concerned about is `pshk_log_write_w()`, the name implying it is chosen because you were compiling as Unicode (I hope). With any luck there is an associated  `pshk_log_write_a()` narrow-version of that function that will automatically be picked up as the intended target when you make the above changes. If not, there may be some places where you'll need to do some wide-to-narrow conversions, but I can only hope not. It is a pain to do so.

Comment: I change the charater set to unicode character set, it works, thank you .

Comment: @king LOL. Changing it TO unicode was something that had not occurred to me. Now that I think about it, if it was intended on being unicode and your new project conversion did not set that, the same issued would arise. Duh. Well, at least you got to the right part of the project properties editor to change it. Glad I could at least help you get that far =P.

Answer (score 2):

TCHAR is Microsoft's macro for either 8 bit chars (char) or 16 bit chars (wchar_t) to help distinguish between Unicode and ASCII strings. They have two distinct API sets in the SDK, so that is why the compiler is compiler. It seems like Visual Studio 2012 defaults to wchar_t instead of char. You can disable it via the options for the project: Right click the project, then click Properties. Under the general section, there should be a Character Set option. Change it from Use Unicode character set to Use MultiByte characters. Read the following page for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321%28v=vs.71%29.aspx Hope that helps.